# Wordpress Floating bar like 9gag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I've read a few posts on stackoverflow and my site's not reacting very well.

My site: http://funnykittenmemes.com/

You can view the source code and Firebug to see the css and javascript I am using.  I'm trying to get the floating bar (below the ad) to stay in fixed position, BUT when a user scrolls down, the bar should stay in place at the top of the pace.  So it stays in place only until a user scrolls down.

I'm trying to use this code: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

No idea what's wrong.  Right now, the bar sticks but it sticks in the same position that it was originally on the site (you can see a space above the bar as you scroll down).  It doesn't stick to the top of the page.

Apparently, this post is "too localized" so here's the code:

In my header file

(before the end head tag)

```
<script src="/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>
<script src="/waypoints/waypoints.js"></script>
```

(after the end head tag)

```
 <header class="header-bar">
     floating bar code here
 </header>
```

In my footer file

(before the end body tag)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.header-bar').waypoint('sticky');
 });
 </script>
```

CSS

```
 header {
 height:40px;
 background-color: #222222;
 padding:0pt;
 min-width: 1060px;
 height:50px;
 border-top: 1px solid #333;
 border-bottom:1px solid #000;
 box-shadow: #000000;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 999;
 position: fixed;
 }

 .header-below {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 height: 180px;
 border-top: 1px solid #333;
 }

 .header-bar.stuck {
 height:40px;
 background-color: #222222;
 padding:0pt;
 min-width: 1060px;
 height:50px;
 border-top: 1px solid #333;
 border-bottom:1px solid #000;
 box-shadow: #000000;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 999;
 position: fixed;
 }
```

The header-below attribute is for the area below the floating bar.

**UPDATE:** Got it working.

Changed the .header-bar.stuck css attribute property to this:

```
 .header-bar.stuck {
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
 }
```

Moved the scripts to the footer file right above the $(document) code
Removed the "min" from "min.js".  Didn't need the "min".

Took me a while to notice but that's what I did.  Make sure that the floating bar has a class and is inside the $(document) code.  The CSS and javascript have to match up.  And make sure you call the right js file in your code.  You can take a look at my source code if you need to :)

Comment: This question is too localized.

Comment: What do you mean by "too localized"?  I saw 2 or 3 other questions related to this exact question.  Only difference is, they posted up the code they were using.  I'll add my code if that makes things better.  And those 2 or 3 questions I saw never had a "solution".  It was a resolved problem that never stated if any solutions worked.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized

Comment: I'll leave this question up in case someone is generous enough to help me out.  I'll try and figure out the problem myself.  It disappoints me how some people don't bother to offer solutions.

Comment: Solved it and posted the solution.  Simple "dumb" questions do require answers sometimes.  The best tech support sites online are open about that.  Encouraging people to solve problems on their own but also offering solutions.

Comment: Hi, user 11114968, please add your solution as an Answer. I think you would've been so downvoted if you posted the code when first asking. Apparently, the problem you had is described in the plugin's page: *`It is left to you, the author, to give the stuck elements fixed positioning in CSS.`*

Comment: Yea, this was a "crap, I missed that" question where I overlook something that causes an error.  I read the plugin page.  Problem was, I fetched the wrong js file.  It's working now so I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the .header-bar.stuck css attribute property to this:

```
 .header-bar.stuck {
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
 }
```

Moved the scripts to the footer file right above the $(document) code. Removed the "min" from "min.js". Didn't need the "min".

Took me a while to notice but that's what I did. Make sure that the floating bar has a class and is inside the $(document) code. The CSS and javascript have to match up. And make sure you call the right js file in your code. You can take a look at my source code if you need to :)